# Did git or visual studio code remove my folder?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

So here's what happened. I am working on a small software development project and I have a git repository that I work on in VS code. So far so good.
I did some restructuring of the project recently and had a few files with bits of code that are not anymore needed, but I want to keep for reference, in case I need them in the future. I put them in a folder called `dev_int` and added a line to my `.gitignore` file to make sure these files meant for internal development don't get published.

```
dev_int/*
```

I know this is probably not the best way to do this, but it seemed to work and was an easy way to achieve what I needed.

Now my `dev_int` folder has disappeared with all of its content. Is this expected behaviour? How should I have gone around doing this?

I am working on ubuntu 22.04, git version 2.34.1 and as mentioned doing all this through VS code.

Comment: Did you run `git clean`?

Comment: Yeah looks like a result of `git clean -x`

Comment: Another explanation is that you temporarily checked out a branch on which you haven't added that folder to gitignore, then added and committed those files on that branch (maybe by mistake), and then checked out main or your previous branch again. Those files will then be deleted since they're not on the branch you're checking out.

Comment: Just so you know: By mentioning files in .gitignore, you tell Git: "These files are expendable. I don't care about them." Git will happily delete the files if it has to. But then, it will do so only when there's a reason and not at any time just because it can.

Comment: `git clean -x ` or `git clean -X`. It might also have been a normal `git clean` if you were on another git branch which didn't ignore those files :)

Comment: Anyway if you actually want to get them back you could always check out a version of the code where you haven't deleted them yet. Git is nice that way :P

Answer (score 0):

> How should I have gone around doing this?

You should have stored these files *outside* the project folder, out of Git's control. The visible contents of the project folder (also known as the working tree) *belongs to Git*, not to you. These are not your files. In fact, the project folder's visible contents are sort of an illusion (or perhaps I should say, a projection) created by Git.

When you turn a folder into a Git repo (either by saying `git clone` or by saying `git init`), from then on, this folder is under the control of Git. The real repo lives inside the invisible *.git* folder at the top level of the project folder; that is where the commits that constitute the repo live. Each commit is a snapshot of all your project's files; but under normal circumstances, you cannot see them. But at the same time, from the repo, Git makes *copies* of some files and puts them into the working tree, so that you can edit them, add them to the index, and create a new commit. It does this based on what commit (typically a branch) you have checked out from the repo (the HEAD). That way, when you do create a new commit, Git can make it the child of the currently checked out commit (and moves the HEAD to point to this new commit).

Git is very nimble about this. When you switch from one branch to another, Git effectively removes everything from the working tree and replaces it with a whole new set of copies, reflecting the branch you have just switched to.

Thus, you must *expect* the contents of the working tree to come and go. That's what the working tree *is*. So if you have some files that are not to be part of the project under Git's control, the safe place to put them is *outside* the working tree — outside the project folder.